# How to uninstall GDB on osx

Tags: gdb, osx-yosemite

I want to uninstall GDB on my MAC. I tried to remove the folder /usr/local/bin/gdb, but when I install it again, it says already installed. Does anybody know how? thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you have tried to install GDB? The current state of GDB on OSX is not very good.

Comment: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/GDB_on_OS_X_Mavericks_and_Xcode_5

Comment: I use this method to install gdb, but it doesn't go so well so i decide to redo it. But I don't know how to uninstall gdb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove GDB from Homebrew, you should use `brew rm gdb`. Simply removing the `/usr/local/bin/gdb` symlink will still leave the formula built, just not linked. You generally shouldn't try to remove Homebrew files manually. Homebrew is a package manager, so let the package manager handle it.